How to stretch some part of a letter?
For example, I'd like to stretch the horizontal line of the letter T and bend it in some way

(This figure is created by PS). Unless one can accurately locate the north west corner and south east corner of the horizontal bar of letter T via tikz，is there an alternative way (such as starting from otf or ttf font)? For some reason, I want to create a hologo that may contain letter like this.

"Except tikz"? If you know how to do this in tikz, it could help to add it, since it can give people ideas on how to do it with other tools. If not, it might be good to explain why you want an alternative to tikz.

The question is edited. Because the letter mostly has serif, then I worry about that tikz may could not locate to the corners of the horizontal bar of letter T accurately. What's more, the font libertine also has very very little serif even though I use \sffamily. @mickep

You could do that in Metapost using the glyph operator to find the exact corners of the "T".

You need to compile this with lualatex:
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{luamplib}
\begin{document}
\begin{mplibcode}
beginfig(1);
  
  picture T, ower, gT;
  T = "T" infont "phvr8r" scaled 20;
  ower = "ower" infont "phvr8r" scaled 20 shifted lrcorner T shifted 24 left;
  gT = glyph "T" of "phvr8r" scaled 1/5;  % glyph returns char scaled 100

  path p;
  for i within gT: p = pathpart i; endfor
  dy = ypart (point 2 of p - point 1 of p);
  p := subpath (0,1) of p {right} 
      .. (xpart urcorner ower, ypart point 1 of p + 30 ) 
      -- (xpart urcorner ower, ypart point 1 of p + 30 + dy)
      .. {left} subpath (2, 7) of p -- cycle;

  draw ower;
  fill p;

endfig;
\end{mplibcode}
\end{document}


Excellent answer.
